# aws ecr is invalid choice

Tags: mac-osx, aws-cli

I want to push my docker images to my ECR on aws.

According to the documentation, I need to run `aws ecr get-login`.

This is what I get:

```
> aws ecr get-login                                                       
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:
```

It is my version of `aws cli`

```
> aws --version
aws-cli/1.9.0 Python/2.7.10 Darwin/16.5.0 botocore/1.3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I need to upgrade awscli to above version 1.9.15

```
brew upgrade awscli
```

And unique to my environment, my version of `aws` was previously installed via `pip` into my python installation. I need to run `pip uninstall awscli` to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading `awscli` is helpful, however if your version is >= 2.0, you will get the same error. Use `get-login-password` instead:

```
aws ecr get-login-password
```